# IFS giving Incorrect output

Tags: bash, ifs

I have a port number file map.ini:

```
50051=1
50052=1
50053=1
50054=1
50055=1
50056=1
```

and a script sample.sh whose contents are:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=map.ini

while IFS='=' read -r port varPortStatus
do
        if [[ $varPortStatus -eq "1" ]]; then
                printf "Available port is %s" $port
                printf "Status is %d." $varPortStatus.
                return 0
        fi
done < "$file"
echo "No port is available"
```

Expected output I need is:

```
Available port is 50051
Status is 1
```

I can do this using `sed` or `cut` command manipulation. But I need to understand with IFS here. I am getting output as:

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
No port is available
```

Please tell where am I doing wrong?

Comment: from the output seems there's may be a dos line ending `\r` in map.ini or in sample.sh, try `dos2unix map.ini`, or `cat -ve map.ini` to verify

Comment: also dot after `$varPortStatus` must be removed otherwise it's invalid for `%d`, and `\n` are missing in printf

Comment: When I do `cat -ve map.ini`, I get `^M$` at the end of each line.

Comment: `^M` is the caret notation mean chr 13 ascii because M is 13th letter in alphabet, the same as `\r` escape notation for cariage return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the output seems there's may be a dos line ending \r in map.ini or in sample.sh, try dos2unix map.ini, or cat -ve map.ini to verify.

if the input file can't be modified `\r` character can be removed in bash

```
while IFS='=' read -r port varPortStatus
do
    varPortStatus=${varPortStatus%$'\r'}
    if [[ $varPortStatus -eq "1" ]]; then
            printf "Available port is %s\n" $port
            printf "Status is %d.\n" $varPortStatus
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Note also fixes `\n` added to format, `.` removed after `$varPortStatus` and `return` valid only in a function or a sourced script.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove `return`. I didn't understand the `varPortStatus%$'\r'` part, although it is '\r' character, from where does it come generally?

Comment: `%` is for removing suffix pattern, for more details see `${parameter%word}` in bash manual, also `$'`..`'` is for ANSI-C quoting

Comment: When I open editor, it shows nothing, either in gedit or vim editor!

Comment: this is because text file format are handled by text editors in vim you should see `[dos]` or `[unix]` in status bar

Comment: Do you mean this documentation? [GNU Org](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Thanks, those are very informative for me. Learnt many things from your answer. :)